# CSS for when the cursor is parked on an element

Tags: javascript, php, css, cursor

I have 2 php files and a js file.  When the div is clicked it goes to the new page with the # appended to the url so it scrolls to that comment ID. It is working where it goes to the page and scrolls to the bottom of the page everytime, even if the comment is not on the bottom of the page.  BUT the correct comment div has the cursor blinking next to it. CSS :focus is not doing anything, I think maybe because the js reloads the window first, then sets it?

1. How can I use that blinking cursor to change the css of the element that has the cursor on it (hover does not work, because the mouse is not hovering, the cursor just has that element selected)
2. how can I make it scroll to correct element and not always bottom

main page

```
echo '<div onclick="goToPage('.$page_id.','.$comment_id.')">the page</div>';
```

new page with comments

```
  <div id="' . $comment_id . '"></div>
```

js

```
<script>
 function goToPage(page_id, comment_id){
   var url = 'index.php?page_id='+page_id+'#'+comment_id;
   document.location.href=url;
</script>
```

Comment: _"BUT the correct comment div has the cursor blinking next to it."_ - why would the cursor _blink_, if it was just "next" to a div? _"CSS :focus is not doing anything"_ - why should it, _did_ you focus anything? (Navigating to a URL with a fragment does not set focus; if anything, `:target` would be applicable in that situation.)

Comment: _"how can I make it scroll to correct element and not always bottom"_ - this _can_ occur if you have too many "layout shifts" during the intial page rendering, so that the browser can not properly calculate the correct position to jump to. Too many big images that load delayed, content dynamically added by JS somewhere in between, etc. - those _could_ all be factors.

Answer (score 1):

If the cursor is blinking next to it, you may be able to use the :focus or :active pseudo-classes in your CSS.

Example:

```
.divClass:active {
   property:value;
}
```

In the event, that does not work. Try using JavaScript's document.activeElement to either add a class for the styling, or do it directly in the JavaScript.